# qWhy am I getting <identifier> expected code?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my part of code written for creating a gamesearch tree which is giving  expected error. What error is it and why is my program throwing it?

```
package player;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Strategy {
    private static int switch (int player) {
        return Math.abs(1 - player);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
player/strategy.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
    private static int switch (int player) {
                      ^
player/strategy.java:12: error: illegal start of type
    private static int switch (int player) {
                              ^
player/strategy.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
    private static int switch (int player) {
                               ^
```

Comment: Why from all the alphabet combinations, you chose `switch`? :/

Comment: @MarounMaroun the pattern |1 - player| is used to switch between 0 and 1. Presumably, `switchPlayer(int)` would be a better name.

Answer (score 1):

`switch` is a reserved keyword. You cannot use it as a method name. You cannot use it as anything other than to declare a [`switch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Answer (score 1):

`switch` is a [**one of the java's reserved keyword**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) you can't name your method to that name, change your method name to fix it